# How to find specific element in my cloned row and change the id of that element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a button to clone a row. And I want to find an input and then change its id.

My function:

```
function cloneRow(tables, rows) {
      var row = document.getElementById(rows); // find row to copy
      var table = document.getElementById(tables); // find table to append to
      var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
      clone.id = rows; // change id or other attributes/contents
      table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}
```

my row to be cloned:

```
<tr id="row">
    <td width="5%"><button type="button" onclick="cloneRow('table', 'row')" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Add</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="removeRow2('table')" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</button></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" required class="form-control" name="txtitemname[]" /></td>
    <td width="30%"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtnote[]" placeholder="e.g. box of milk, bottles of water" /></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="background-color:#FFF" id="expiration-date" name="txtexpiration[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" required min="1" value="1" class="form-control" name="txtquantity[]" /></td>
</tr>
```

I want to change the id of expiration-date to expiration-date1 when it is cloned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {




    });
    function cloneRow() {
        var objRow;
        objRow = $('#row').clone();
        $(objRow).find('#expiration-date').attr('id', 'expiration-date' + $('#tbl_sample tr').length);
        $(objRow).attr('id', 'row_' + $('#tbl_sample tr').length)
        $('#tbl_sample').append($(objRow));
    }

</script>



<body>
  <table id="tbl_sample">

      <tr id="row">
    <td width="5%"><button type="button" onclick="cloneRow()" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Add</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="removeRow2('table')" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</button></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" required class="form-control" name="txtitemname[]" /></td>
    <td width="30%"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtnote[]" placeholder="e.g. box of milk, bottles of water" /></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="background-color:#FFF" id="expiration-date" name="txtexpiration[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" required min="1" value="1" class="form-control" name="txtquantity[]" /></td>
</tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can i increment it every time it cloned? if I have expiration-date2 the next will be expiration-date3.

Comment: Thank you sir :). you saved my day :)